# who does the signer address in ethers-js belong to?

Tags: ether, etherscan, ethers.js

I deployed a random contract on the rinkeby network (contract address is 0x38a287C93e2B1Cd50719aEA8D8d33A263554c099), and when I connect to the contract with ethers-js like this:

```
const contract = await (await ethers.getContractFactory('Sink'))
                 .attach('0x38a287C93e2B1Cd50719aEA8D8d33A263554c099');

let signerAddress = await contract.signer.getAddress();
console.log('signerAddress:', signerAddress);
```

If I run above snippet the output is: `signerAddress: 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266`
and that is not an address that is connected to me in any way. Here it is on etherscan: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266.

Is this an arbitrary address chosen by ethers-js? I would have thought that the address signing my actions would be mine. Why is this not the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the first address (`m/44'/60'/0'/0/0`) derived from the mnemonic phrase `test test test test test test test test test test test junk`. Ethers likely uses this mnemonic phrase when you don't specify a signer yourself.

If you wish to use your own signer (which you should), you can do something like this:

```js
const contract = await ethers.getContractFactory(...);
const contractWithSigner = contract.connect(yourOwnSigner);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sign by your private key also like web3 js. If you want to sign your wallet then you have to provide either your mnemonic phrase or private key. So it is quite easy to sign by your private key.
For example:

```
let signWallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey,provider);
```

here by giving the private key and provider address like your json rpc url you can sign your wallet and you will get a response like
[image]

Look here it shows **"_isSigner": true,** that means its now sign.